# How to get a description from glossary entry?

Tags: glossaries

I define my entry with:

```
\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo}, description={foo description}}
```

I can refer to it in a text with \Gls{foo} which puts a href link to Glossary.
Is is possible to get a raw string with description from glossary entry?
For example

```
The term \gls{foo} is defined as: \GlsDesc{foo}
```

or something like this. I'd like it to output a raw description text without hreflinks and such in the middle of the text.

So the output of that would be:

```
The term foo is defined as: foo description
```

Is it possible ?

EDIT: It would be nice if a reference to another glossary entry in description wouldn't break:

```
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={bar}, description={bar description}}
\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo}, description={foo and \gls{bar} description}}

This is foo desc: \glsdesc{foo}
```

The reference is broken, this is the output:

```
This is foo desc: foo and ``gls-bar`` description
```

instead of expected:

```
This is foo desc: foo and bar description
```

Comment: Please, turn the code snippet into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem that you described in your edited post. `\glsdesc` seems to break nested `\gls`. Hope that someone knows a workaround or how to fix it.

Comment: @christoph: The effect you observe is due to the special ‘sanitization’ applied to the values of the `name`, `description` and `symbol` keys. Hence, try `\usepackage[sanitize=none]{glossaries}` and then `\glsdesc*{foo}`. Note that, without sanitization, you have to protect fragile commands in the arguments of `\newglossaryentry`. But fortunately, `\gls` is robust.

Comment: @mhp: Thank you very much. It's working now.

Comment: @mhp: If you change your comment into an answer, I could award the bounty to it (if you are interested).

Comment: @christoph: Done.

Answer (score 7):

This command is called `\glsdesc{<your key>}` Analogous to the `symbol` commands there are three versions of this command:

```
\glsdesc{<your key>}
\Glsdesc{<your key>} 
\GLSdesc{<your key>}
```

And of course the starred versions:

```
\glsdesc*{<your key>}
\Glsdesc*{<your key>} 
\GLSdesc*{<your key>}
```

The latter should meet your demands.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. However what If my description contains a reference to another glossary:

    (...)description = {This item is related to \gls{another} item mentioned earlier}.

Comment: In that case it would be quite helpful if you would add a MWE showing your construction.

Answer (score 5):

The first part of the above question has already been correctly answered by @bloodworks. So I’m only addressing the second part, as in my original comment.

The situation is the following: To ease the usage of *fragile* commands in glossary definitions, the [`glossaries`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) package ‘sanitizes’ the values of the `name`, `description` and `symbol` keys using the LaTeX 2ε kernel command `\@onelevel@sanitize`. As a result, each of these values is replaced with a character string preserving the respective *unexpanded* meaning.

Obviously, this procedure is convenient when it comes to writing the values of the `name`, `description` and `symbol` keys to the output glossary file (i.e. the auxiliary file with the filename extension `.gls`). On the other hand, it possibly fails when one of these values is typeset directly via `\glsname`, `\glsdesc` or `\glssymbol`.

In a nutshell, if you want to reference glossary entries using `\glsname`, `\glsdesc` or `\glssymbol` you might consider completely turning off the sanitization procedure. To this end, load the `glossaries` package as

```
\usepackage[sanitize=none]{glossaries}
```

Alternatively, you can disable the sanitization procedure only for a subset of the three affected keys. Try, for instance,

```
\usepackage[sanitize={description=false}]{glossaries}
```

Of course, turning off the sanitization procedure possibly requires adaptations to existing glossary definitions: Fragile commands have to be protected (e.g. by prefixing them with `\protect` from the LaTeX 2ε kernel) or made robust prior to usage (e.g. by means of `\robustify` from the  [`etoolbox`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) package).